# How to ask for an update on a potential opening?

Tags: job-search, internship

I am currently interning at HP. During the school year I would like to intern at a different much smaller company. When I first asked them they were going through some internal changes and told me to ask again later in the summer.

What is the best way for me to ask them if the position is available?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way for me to ask them if the position is available
>   for me?

There's no magic here. They already indicated exactly what you should do.

Wait until it's "later in the summer", then just ask! Say "Hey, remember you told me to ask again later in the summer? So is that intern position available?"

Depending on how long ago you first approached them will tell you how long you have to wait before asking again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you email. You are telling them that you are following upon on their  request of several months ago that they follow up with you in the summer when you asked them if the position is open. It is now the middle of the summer, and are they now ready to tell you whether a position is open? And that you definitely want to be considered as a candidate for the position and that you are looking forward to hearing from them.